# For Loop with a function call doesn't seem to be waiting for await inside the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, async-await, promise

Sorry about the confusing title.
So what I basically have is a function with a for-loop, calling another function in the loop, which has a call with an 'await' inside it. the function inside pushes values into an array once the async/await call is done. The value of the array is then returned once the loop is complete.

Something like this:

```
let globalArray = [];

const innerFunction = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1);
    }, 100);
  });
};

const callingFunction = async () => {
  let a = await innerFunction();
  globalArray.push(a);
  console.log(`GLOBAL ARRAY AFTER PUSH IN THE CALLING FUCNTION`);
  console.log(globalArray);
};


const outerFunction = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    callingFunction();
    console.log(`GLOBAL ARRAY AFTER FUCTION CALL`);
    console.log(globalArray);
  }
  console.log(`GLOBAL ARRAY AFTER FOR LOOP END ${globalArray}`);
  console.log(globalArray);
};
```

What I have observed is that the value of `globalArray` does not change in the logs both inside and right after the for loop (logs `globalArray` as `[]`), but the log inside the `callingFunction` right after the `push` statement seems to log `globalArray` as `[1]`.

This would indicate that the `await` statement isn't being waited upon by the primary function call in the for loop.

Ideally, I would expect all the log statements to log `globalArray` as `[1]`.

Why would this be happening? Is there a better way to do this? I can't change the call pattern per se, because in my actual implementation, each function has additional things to do.

I've put this implementation up on stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-i8jusx?file=index.ts

Comment: Your code will only wait for an `async` function to complete if you `await` it. You're not awaiting `callingFunction()` so it wont wait.

Comment: @Ivar Ah, okay. So, would it be a good practice to return another Promise from `callingFunction()` to `outerFunction()`?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pponjw?file=index.ts

Comment: It already does. An `async` function implicitly returns a Promise. And you can only `await` Promises. (Well, technically anything that has a `.then()` method.) Note that `async` and `await` is nothing more than syntactic sugar over Promises.

Comment: Please read [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](/q/23803743/4642212) and [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](/a/44476626/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `await` keyword in `outerFunction` when calling `callingFunction`.

```
const outerFunction = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    await callingFunction();
    console.log(`GLOBAL ARRAY AFTER FUCTION CALL`);
    console.log(globalArray);
  }
  console.log(`GLOBAL ARRAY AFTER FOR LOOP END ${globalArray}`);
  console.log(globalArray);
};
```

Remember that an `async` function automatically returns a `Promise`, even if it is `Promise<void>`